# What is the fastest spinning rotation of a Neutron star?

Tags: rotation, neutron-star, speed

What is the fastest spinning rotation of a Neutron star? I have heard that Neutron stars have a specially fast spinning rotation. What is the fastest?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it turns out, the fastest spinning neutron star found yet is a [pulsar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar) 18000 light years away in the constelation of Sagittarius which scientist catalogued as [**PSR J1748-2446ad**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_J1748-2446ad). Pulsars are neutron stars that rotate, are highly magnetic and emit a strong perpendicular beam of electromagnetic radiation.

This pulsar's speed is such that:

> At its equator it is spinning at approximately 24% of the speed of light, or over 70,000 km per second.

**PSR J1748-2446ad** rotates a little over 700 times a second, and scientists have this to say on the theoretical limits of the rotation speed of a pulsar ([from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond_pulsar)):

> Current theories of neutron star structure and evolution predict that pulsars would break apart if they spun at a rate of ~1500 rotations per second or more, and that at a rate of above about 1000 rotations per second they would lose energy by gravitational radiation faster than the accretion process would speed them up.

Comment: Fun experiment. Go here https://meettechniek.info/additional/additive-synthesis.html select Impuls, type the number 716 in the Sound Frequency field, and raise the volume. The sound you're hearing is the rotation frequency of the pulsar PSR J1748-2446ad.

Comment: Wow, that also means that such an ultrafast rotating NS is essentially a kinetic energy -> gravitational wave converter.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest celestial body we know so far is neutron star XTE J1739-285. It rotates 1122 times per second. Source: https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.4310?fbclid=IwAR2g9RYhybbBlxxzKOfquBa9C33H8mMwuZ_mHZbm1RbcsetrxO3vbvXq7gA

Comment: [Chakrabarty (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4031) reports that the measurement of the sub-millisecond spin is marginal. Furthermore [Drago et al. (2008)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/?#abs/2008ApJ...678L.117D) suggest that such an object would have to be a quark star or a hybrid quark-hadron star.